# Separated input text fields for single input field

Tags: forms, symfony

Is there any Symfony2 option to show some separated text fields from one single text field in a form?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use form customization feature. Please check this article for more information -http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html
Example:

form_theme.twig.html

```
{% block file_widget %}
    {% spaceless %}
     <td>{% set type = type|default('file') %}
         <input type="{{ type }}" {{ block('widget_attributes') }} />
     </td>
    {% endspaceless %}
{% endblock file_widget %}
```

template.twig.html

```
{% form_theme form 'MyBundle:Form:form_theme.html.twig' %}
{{ form_row(form.contract) }}
```